# Reading PDF in net core with itext7 returns "\n\n\n\n\n...."

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

i have a netcore 3 app to read and split a PDF containing paychecks of some companies which i am working for.

This app ran pretty well since last builds... my the way, the PDF reader started to fail to parse the contents of any PDF.

PDF is built only with Italian words, no special chars. Few tables and a single logo. I'm not able to attach it due to privacy.

```
    public PaycheckSplitter Read()
    {
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(this._stream)))
        {
            var doc = new PdfDocument(reader);


            this.Paycheck = new PaychecksCollection();

            for (int i = 1; i <= doc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                PdfPage page = doc.GetPage(i);

                string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
                if (text.Contains(Consts.BpEnd)) break;

                // trying to find something by regex... btw text contains only a sequence of \n\n\n\n...
                string cf = Consts.CodFiscale.Match(text).Value;                     
                this.Paychecks.Add(new Paycheck(cf), i);
            }
            doc.Close();
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Anything i can do?
As far as i can see... the only and best way to have something to read a PDF text for free is iText7...

Comment: iText 7 is not *the only way* but it usually is a good way to read PDF text. If you have PDFs iText 7 can not extract the text from, representative examples of those PDFs must be analyzed to understand and probably fix the issue. If Adobe Reader also cannot successfully copy&paste from those files, chances are that the PDF has been created with serious measures to prevent text extraction; in that case you may need to build a specialized text extractor for those documents, you may even have to resort to OCR.

Comment: copy&paste works pretty well from this PDF... there are pretty straightforward PDF. And also: my solution worked since few builds ago.

Any idea of other freewares libs to export text from a PDF (150/160 pages)? All the existing are freemium and they are not workin on a win server system... and unfortunately i'm running my dev env on a Win Server PC.

Comment: I'm afraid those are not *pretty straightforward PDFs*, otherwise iText 7 would not have issues extracting the text. PDFs sometimes look simple when rendered but are weird internally.

Comment: Sure... you're totally right mate. So, after testing and trying solutions, maybe i fouond something better than iText: Syncfusion, which is for free as individual developer with very low incomes. A pretty good solution...

Comment: @sslazio1900 hi, can you share the PDF?

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't @AlexeySubach . The PDF i'm splitting is the sum of the paychecks of an entire company, so data contained in the file is strictly personal.