# Reading PDF text via iText7 for a page no longer returns content after switching to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext7

We have a multiple APIs built using .NET Core 2.2 (but just recently migrated to 3.1) that generate PDFs using iText7 (specifically v7.1.5) and a QA project with API regression tests that validate the PDF generation processes. We have no issue generating the PDFs using iText7 within these APIs, but when trying to read the content using these API regression tests (in the QA project), we see no content.

Example code to read PDF content (and specifically look for a page that contains "Index of Legislation" on it which if you look at the linked PDF is found on page 8):

```
bool foundIndex = false;
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath))
{
    using (var doc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(reader))
    {
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= doc.GetNumberOfPages(); ctr++)
        {
            var page = doc.GetPage(ctr); var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
            foreach (string textWord in text.Split("\n"))
            {
                if (textWord.Trim() == "Index of Legislation")
                {
                    foundIndex = true;
                }
            };
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

A sample generated file is available [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/fjec0wfwai5f3yp/samplecalendar.pdf/file). I have verified using [PDFXplorer](https://www.o2sol.com/pdfxplorer/overview.htm) as well as [PDF Analyzer](https://www.winking.be/en/products/pdfanalyzer) that there is text on each page. I have tried introducing an ITextExtractionStrategy implementation e.g.

```
var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
```

or

```
var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

but it didn't change anything in terms of returning text content. I have scoured iTextpdf.com (iText7 site) for anything on breaking changes as well as other StackOverflow posts; the closest I found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003744/reading-pdf-in-net-core-with-itext7-returns-n-n-n-n-n) but it didn't look like a solution was found other than the author going the route of syncfusion. I should note that I have upgraded iText7 version to 7.1.16 as well but still no change.

Comment: Hi, do I understand correctly that it worked for .NET Core 2.2 but does not work for .NET Core 3.1? If so, then the issue is not in your code itself but in the dependencies etc, so could you attach a minimal sample project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I was able to write a short and very concise separate .NET Core 3.1 console app that did not recreate this problem (e.g. it works and reads text just fine with just a nuget package reference to itext7); I am currently thinking our QA project must have incompatible references causing this problem and with some other developers, we are evaluating this right now.